# open app url scheme without option to go to store if not available windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, url-scheme, custom-url

On IOS and Android it's easy to detect wether a certain app is installed or not. Microsoft is not as friendly for developers and denies the access to information about other apps.

So when launching an url scheme on WP like:

```
 Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new system.Uri("myApp:MyParams"));
```

This would open a dialog you can either cancel or "go to store to download the app".

I would like to get a result where this dialog is never shown when the app is not installed and when it is installed the app just opens.

So can anyone help me with that? (of course more ideally would be an availability check but that's not gonna happen so)

Comment: I am not sure that's possible. This is the default behavior of the platform.

Comment: I know but I hope there is a lupole to alter this behavior

Comment: Maybe this link will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779672.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in 8.1, you have to wait for 10 where there is more functionality provided for `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync`.

Comment: Tested it for WP10 and works "great"(nothing works great yet... but it does the trick)

Comment: Specifically, in Windows 10 you can use the `QueryUriSupportAsync` method to see if anyone can handle the launch: [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.queryurisupportasync.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call method `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` with  `LauncherOptions` param.

`LauncherOptions.preferredApplicationPackageFamilyName` Is set to the package family name of the app in the store that you want to recommend.

`LauncherOptions.preferredApplicationDisplayName` Is set to the name of that app LauncherOptions.

You must set both of these options to recommend an app. Setting one without the other will result in a failure.